# Get a Tx hash from truffle

Tags: web3js, truffle

I have implemented a function call in truffle(web3js):

```
await this.token1.transferFrom(holder1, holder2, transferAmount, {from: holder1});
```

and now I want to get the tx hash for that specific function. Any ideas, I'm quite new with truffle so I don't really know.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
const response = await this.token1.transferFrom(holder1, holder2, transferAmount, {from: holder1});
const hash = response.tx;
```

You can print the response and see every piece of data available:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
```